# What is the formula for this pattern?

Tags: computer-science, inverse

I'm trying to find some sort of inverse relationship between two variables.  I am working on some parallax scrolling in my iPhone app and I'd like to see if someone can help me find the formula for this data.

I don't think context is needed, so I'll just skip how I got this data and just go straight to the results.

I did some experimenting with a simple input variable and got my output variable, but I want to know a method for converting the input to the output.  Here is my table:

`x    |    y`

`.01  |  100`

`.1   |   10`

`.25  |    4`

`.5   |  2.0`

`.75  |~1.31`

`1    |    1`

`1.25 |  ~.8`

`1.5  |~.663`

`1.75 |~.575`

`2.0  |   .5`

`4    |  .25`

`10   |   .1`

`100  |  .01`

Comment: Could $x \times y=1$ be satisfactory answer ?

Comment: @KKendall There is to be a mistake in your data. In the $y$ column third value, I can hardly imagine that is .395

Comment: Yeah, looks like your right.  It should be 4.  I added the ~ to show that it was an approximation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you!  It was such a simple formula!  Please write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think the decimal point in that entry is the problem -- it should be 3.95, not .395, right?  And @ClaudeLeibovici is probably correct -- the formula you are looking for seems to be $y=1/x$.

Comment: Oh, oops... yeah.

Comment: Just updated it to 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the data in excel and try scatter-plot. From there you can make the trend line of power type. You will see that y=1/x is the approximate function that represent the given data.